# How to make reactive UI when variable is changed in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm not sure that I understand how to keep my web application reactive with Meteor.

I have this very simple template

```
<body>
{{> simple}}
</body>

<template name="simple">
    Counter: {{counter}} <br/>
    <button>Increase</button>
</template>
```

And client side script

```
var counter = 0;

Template.simple.counter = function () {
    return counter;
}

Template.simple.events({
    'click button': function () {
        counter++;
        console.log("counter is ", counter);
        Meteor.flush();
    }
});
```

When clicking on button I can see in console that `counter` variable is increasing properly but nothing happens on UI. Why? I thought it's exactly what `Meteor.flush()` is intended to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UI isn't reactive all by itself, you need to use one of Meteor's reactive items. In this case, you probably want to use `Session`. Try the following, instead of the second script you pasted:

```
Session.set('counter', 0); // Initialize a *reactive* variable

Template.simple.counter = function () {
    return Session.get('counter'); // This will automatically update, because Session is reactive
}

Template.simple.events({
    'click button': function () {
        Session.set('counter', Session.get('counter') + 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: It's bad practice to clutter session with local variables. It's better to use Deps.Dependency in such cases.

Comment: @HubertOG that is true, but when you're just beginning, like in this case, it's best to play around with everything and get an idea of how reactivity works before you get into things like `Deps` yourself, which is more complicated. And `Session` is an excellent way to play around with UI reactivity.

Comment: @BenjaminRH you can also look at https://github.com/awwx/meteor-variable if you're really dependant on the session scope

Answer (score 3):

You could also build your own reactive data source:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Sort = {
    sort: 1,

    dep: new Deps.Dependency,

    get: function () {
      this.dep.depend();
      return this.sort;
    },

    toggle: function () {
      this.sort *= -1;
      this.dep.changed();
    }
  };

  Template.leaderboard.players = function () {
    return Players.find({}, {sort: {score: Sort.get(), name: 1}});
  };

  Template.leaderboard.events({
    'click input.sort': function () {
      Sort.toggle();
    }
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Meteor provides the `reactive-var` package, see here : http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar_pkg

> To use ReactiveVar, add the reactive-var package to your project by running in your terminal:
>
> ```
> meteor add reactive-var
> ```